# Facebook API - Can't send messages via request

Tags: javascript, node.js, messenger

unfortunately, I'm unable to send a request using the request npm. Many tutorials and also Facebook itself shows that it should work like my example below but Facebook won't send the message at all.

I already tried to send the request via CURL and the message was sent. I used the same sender ID and message as in my node file.

```js
function callSendAPI(sender, message) {
    let requestBody = {
        "messaging_type": "RESPONSE",
        "recipient": {
            "id": sender
        },
        "message": {
            "text": message
        }
    };

    let url =  "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/me/messages?access_token="+process.env.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN;

    request.post({
        "uri": url,
        "json": requestBody
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('message sent!')
        } else {
            console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
        }
    });
}
```

And also the CURL request:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "message":{
    "text":"hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

The terminal will always say that the message was sent when it wasn't.

Links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

Comment: did you debug "res" too? console.log(res);

Comment: have you got the link to facebooks example, and FWI your requestBody is not valid json

Comment: @DanStarns added the links now. What do you mean by "not valid json"? Because of the variables?

Comment: you'll need to use `JSON.stringify(requestBody)` because at the moment it's still a javascript object. I'm not sure if request automatically parses your object.

Comment: in your url, should it be `access_token` not `access-token`?

Comment: @DanStarns It seems like it automatically parses the JSON but I added it to be safe. Good catch with URL but it also doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried logging the res,  what @luschn said?

Comment: The response returns a huge response. It says that there has to be a valid recipient id but I also logged the JSON now and it's exactly the same as I used for the CURL request.

Comment: please add the exact CURL request, so we can compare it.

Comment: I added the curl request now, sorry